# using grunt-usemin to store minified references at dynamic path

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

In one of the project that I am working on, we need to create a folder named after version of the project and the minified JavaScript and CSS files are stored there. As per usemin's documentation, to update the reference in the HTML page, we need to add the build comment.

```
<!-- build:js 1.2.5/Combinedjs.js -->
<script src="file1.js"></script>
<script src="file2.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

I want the name of folder mentioned above (1.2.5) to be dynamic and I don't want to change the build comment every time before running the grunt tasks. Does usemin provide any options to achieve this?

Comment: I got to know that there is no way to achieve this using grunt-usemin. Check the details on following URL: https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/177#issuecomment-24443221

Answer (score 0):

Take a look an alternative project named grunt-applymin: https://github.com/ghosert/grunt-applymin

Comment: please try and avoid link-only posts.

Comment: It seems that applymin needs python to be installed. I don't want to install Python just for this purpose.